# What argument do I give to my function (when I seem no to...)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class User:
    def sign_in():
        print('logged in')

class Wizard(User):
    def __init__(self, name, power, damage):
        self.name = name
        self.power = power
        self.damage = damage

    def attack():
        print(f'attacking with {self.power} inflicting {self.damage}')

class Archer(User):
    def __init__(self, name, bow, damage, arrows_left):
        self.name = name
        self.bow = bow
        self.damage = damage
        self.arrows_left = arrows_left

    def attack():
        print(f'{self.name} attacking with {self.bow} inflicting {self.damage}, arrows left: {self.arrows_left}')
        #self.arrows_left -= 1
        #print (self.arrows_left)


archer1 = Archer('Robin', 'longbow', '50', 50)
archer1.attack()
```

It gives an error:

```
TypeError: attack() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

What argument do I pass to this function?

And more: I want archers arrows to be updated every time I call `archer.attack()` - how to do it?

Comment: Please fix your code indentation - it's crucial in Python. Also, class member functions typically have their first parameter named `self` so you can access it.

Comment: @iBug More specifically, the *name* doesn't matter, but there needs to be *a* parameter defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` is not a keyword; it is the conventional name for the required first argument of an instance method.

```
def attack(self):
    print(f'{self.name} attacking with {self.bow} inflicting {self.damage}, arrows left: {self.arrows_left}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot **init** the underscores in your code.
But your code is very messy the way you display it now.

```
class User:
    def sign_in():
        print('logged in')

class archer(User):
    def __init__(self, name, bow, damage, arrows_left)   
       self.name = name
       self.bow = bow
       self.damage = damage
       self.arrows_left = arrows_left
        
    def attack(self):
        print(f'attacking with {self.power} inflicting {self.damage}')
```